# didn't get ConcurrentModificationException with duplicate element after creating the Iterator

Tags: java

I am new to java and have doubt in Hashset.

can somebody explain me why we don't get ConcurrentModificationException in case if we add duplicate elements after creating the iterator. anyway we are changing its structure and it should throw exception even if add duplicate element.
can somebody please clear my doubt..

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: Please cover [my tutorial on HashSet](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-hashset-in-java.html) to know its internal life well! When you add duplicate to hashset nothing happens, your new element is not added !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set by definition contains only unique objects. The add operation is divided into two processes: first check if the object is already present in set, then add it if it is not.

When the item that we want to add to the Set is already there, nothing will be changed therefore the exception cannot occur.

Answer (score 7):

Adding a duplicate element does not modify the set, as a set by definition contains only one of each element. This is stated in the javadoc for [Set.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29):

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). **If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.**

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html) :

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and listIterator
>   methods are fail-fast: if the list is structurally modified at any
>   time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the
>   iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent
>   modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than
>   risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time
>   in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed
>   as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees
>   in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. **Fail-fast
>   iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort
>   basis.** Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended
>   on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of
>   iterators should be used only to detect bugs.